# React Native ImageSlider component not scaling

Tags: javascript, react-native

I am using ImageSlider package for representing images in a slideshow, so u can slide images but for some reason it is not scaling. The whole image does not fit on one slide so u have to use ur finger to move to see the whole image.

Here is the code I am using:

```
<ImageSlider autoPlayWithInterval={5000} images={this.state.images}
        customSlide={({ index, item, style, width }) => (
                                     <Image source={{ uri: item }} style={{width: Dimensions.get('window').width}} />
        )}
/>
```

Also I tried to remove the whole customSlide attribute still same problem.

this is the library: https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-image-slider

Screenshop uploaded UPDATE:
This is how it looks inside app:
[image]

And this is how the image looks outside app, original size
[image]

Answer (score 0):

This fixed for me:

```
<ImageSlider autoPlayWithInterval={5000} images={this.state.images}
                                 customSlide={({ index, item, style, width }) => (
                                     <Image source={{ uri: item }} style={{
                                         width: Dimensions.get('window').width,
                                         resizeMode: 'contain',
                                         backgroundColor: 'white'
                                     }} />
                                 )}
                    />
```